# How to add side-effects when using "useReducer"?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to know what options do I have if I need to add some side-effects when using the **useReducer** hook.

For example, there is a TODO-app:

```
const initialState = {items: []};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, action.newItem]
      };

    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'ADD', newItem: 123 })}>
      Add item
    </button>
  );
}
```

**I need to save new items to the server.** The question is: **Where I should place this code?**

(remember, that **reducer** should be pure)

Comment: Use redux-saga or redux-thunk?

Answer (score 9):

The `useEffect` hook is likely what you'd want to use. As the name suggests, it's precisely for doing side-effects per each render cycle. A small refactor to allow this within the component.

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // new item! dispatch state update, send to server, and reset newItem
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD', newItem });
      sendNewItemToServer(newItem);
      setNewItem(null);
    },
    [newItem],
  );

  const newItemHandler = item => setNewItem(item);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => newItemHandler(123)}>
      Add item
    </button>
  );
}
```

This is easy while your app is small, but as it get larger you may want to consider an app level event handling system, such as rxjs & redux/epics, redux sagas, redux thunks. These all rely on redux as the main source of app state truth and can handle the asynchronous calls to API's to send and retrieve data.

Comment: What if I simply put `dispatch` and `sendNewItemToServer` into the `newItemHandler`? Are there any pros and cons? Thanks!

Comment: @J.Snow You could do that. Like I said, though, this is easy to do and maintain at small scale, but as soon as your application gets more complicated and multiple components can start sharing state and/or behaviors, you'll appreciate both the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) principles. Both Redux (state management) and RXJS/sagas/thunks (behaviors) are common tools for attaining both.

Comment: @DrewReese 
I am not sure I see a situation where this isn't scalable.
Can't you just useEffect to hoist shared state and have multiple reducers affecting portions of it?

Maybe a situation where a user is altering state on two different components with different reducers that affect the same section of state? But I am not sure this isnt an unrealistic example

Comment: With React 18 double-executing useEffect in strict mode, this is not a good idea anymore...

Comment: @mb21 React `StrictMode` has *never* double-invoked the `useEffect` hook callback. In React 18 the component is mounted, and from what I read, the component is ***simulated*** to unmount and mount again, keeping the result of the first mount. I see your point though. The `useEffect` hook is still the correct location for issuing side-effects, so if there is any issue at all it's not immediately clear to me what would need to be changed. I don't suspect there's any issue though. (*would need to test this to confirm*)

Comment: @DrewReese You're right that React 18 in strict mode won't "dobule-invoke" useEffect, but it will remount the component twice, and therefore "double-execute" (as I wrote) the hook. That's why any side-effects in there will run twice, which is bad if they're not idempotent.