# Is there a proper approach to use a side-effect in a React's reducer or otherwise encapsulate side-effects using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a timer-like component, and my current approach is based on a single reducer and a ref for the timer, like this:

```
const timerRef = useRef<number | null>(null)
const initialTimerState = {
    isRunning: false,
    startTime: null as Date | null,
    elapsedTime: 0,
}

const [timerState, timerDispatch] = useReducer((state, action: 'start' | 'pause' | 'resume' | 'stop' | 'tick') => {
    const startTicking = () => timerRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
        timerDispatch('tick')
        console.log('tick')
    }, 1000)
    const stopTicking = () => {
        if(timerRef.current) window.clearInterval(timerRef.current)
        timerRef.current = null
    }

    switch (action) {
        case 'start':
            startTicking()
            return {
                ...state,
                isRunning: true,
                startTime: new Date(),
            }
        case 'pause':
            stopTicking()
            return {
                ...state,
                isRunning: false,
            }
        case 'resume':
            startTicking()
            return {
                ...state,
                isRunning: false,
            }
        case 'stop':
            stopTicking()
            return {
                // ...state,
                isRunning: false,
                startTime: null,
                elapsedTime: 0,
            }
        case 'tick':
            if(!state.startTime) return state
            return {
                ...state,
                elapsedTime: Math.round((new Date().getTime() - state.startTime.getTime()) / 1000),
            }
    }
}, initialTimerState)

// and then some buttons that use timerDispatch on click
```

The problem with this approach, technically, is that on dispatching an action, React runs the reducer twice, so when starting, 2 timers are created, and on pause only one of them is destroyed (`clearInterval`), thus pause doesn't work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894698/3995261) sheds some light on how this happens internally, but I'd like to understand whether reducers are supposed to only be pure (and idempotent?) or there is a "React way" to handle this (**?**). Sure, I can remove `useReducer` altogether and turn those actions into just some functions, but given that the component has a complex state, it feels natural to use a reducer here.

One [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60698085/3995261) I've found is to move the effect outside the reducer and use a separate helper for that. But this leads to an amount of repetitive code and also makes the code more fragile, because one updating this code has to at least remember that they have to use wrappers in click handlers, not `timerDispatch`:

```
const [timerState, timerDispatch] = useReducer((state, action: 'start' | 'pause' | 'resume' | 'stop' | 'tick') => {
    switch (action) {
        case 'start':
            return {
                ...state,
                isRunning: true,
                startTime: new Date(),
            }
        case 'pause':
            return {
                ...state,
                isRunning: false,
            }
        case 'resume':
            return {
                ...state,
                isRunning: false,
            }
        case 'stop':
            return {
                // ...state,
                isRunning: false,
                startTime: null,
                elapsedTime: 0,
            }
        case 'tick':
            if(!state.startTime) return state
            return {
                ...state,
                elapsedTime: Math.round((new Date().getTime() - state.startTime.getTime()) / 1000),
            }
    }
}, initialTimerState)

const startTicking = () => timerRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
    timerDispatch('tick')
    console.log("tick")
}, 1000)
const stopTicking = () => {
    if(timerRef.current) window.clearInterval(timerRef.current)
    timerRef.current = null
}

const startTimer = () => {
    timerDispatch('start')
    startTicking()
}
const pauseTimer = () => {
    timerDispatch('pause')
    stopTicking()
}
const resumeTimer = () => {
    timerDispatch('resume')
    startTicking()
}
const stopTimer = () => {
    timerDispatch('stop')
    stopTicking()
}

// and then some buttons that use startTimer and others on click
```

Is there a way to make this enough DRY and with proper encapsulation (without turning this into a class component)?

PS As written, the code has an issue with resuming (accounts pause time as well), which I fix using another state property, but that's not important for the discussed issue.